# Bootstrap image not adjusting height according to parent

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some buttons with images. The images inside of the button are too big. I want the images to resize with the button element, either when the height of the button is changed or text-size is changed. I'm using the Bootstrap-4 class    ("img-fluid") but it doesn't like it's working properly as the image height isn't changing.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="order-type-buttons col-12 d-flex" aria-label="First group">
<button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-8 button-text">Online Pick Up</div>
    <div class="col-4 span-img">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/online-pickup-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" role="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-8 button-text">Online Take out</div>
    <div class="col-4 span-img">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/online-take-out-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-8 button-text">Pick up</div>
    <div class="col-4 span-img">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/pick-up-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</button>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
  .btn{
    white-space: normal;
}


.button-text{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.order-type-btn-blue{
    background-color: #0082d5;
    font-size:14px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.order-type-buttons {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.span-img{
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0.313em;
}
```

Here is how my buttons look:
[image]

Here is how my buttons look after I change the button height to 46px and font-size to 9px.

[image]

Here an image of the buttons with text div and image div with borders:
[image]

Comment: I also found that the div with the text also being responsive either and I added borders to visualize the containers and edited the button height within the dev tools and both the image and the text inside of the button aren't being responsive when the changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

The image is responsive to the width, not the height. So as you reduce the button height, since the width is not reducing, neither is the image height.

You'd need to add some code to make it responsive to the height.

This is one way that works in some cases. Its probably not the best way. If you set a height on the image container, and set a max height on the img

```
.span-img {
    height: 100%;

    /* optional for right align */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: flex-end;

}

.img-fluid {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

That makes the image responsive to the height as well.

See it in action with bootstrap

https://codepen.io/arthurrandom/pen/wRwMvw

The extra flex settings on the .span-img are to hard align to the right, and not necessary for the responsive height image.

Comment: I tested out the CSS code that you provided. It didn't affect the image and when I played with the max-height percentage in the dev tools it also didn't affect it either.

Answer (score 0):

just set the width and set height to auto cause in many cases the bootstrap take height as auto with defined with

or

use percentage , vh scale for height for responsiveness.